# Trying to find a shape with one fontname and replace its font to another

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I wrote a code to ask user input a fontname and then use VBA to search the whole presentation for shapes that bears this font and replace to another.

However, my code somehow doesn't work.
I figure the reason is this line "If sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = searchFont Then" The fontname return from the user input is just text, but this line need it to be within " ". (eg. "Arial")

if anyone has a solution to this, please kindly help me.
Thanks in advance

```
Sub ReplaceFont()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim sh As Shape
Dim searchFont As String

searchFont = InputBox("Please enter font to search.", "Font Search Function")

On Error Resume Next


For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each sh In sld.Shapes
If sh.HasTextFrame = True Then
If sh.TextFrame.HasText = True Then

    If Ucase(sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name) = Ucase(searchFont) Then
        With sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        End With

    End If
End If
End If
Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `On Error Resume Next` - does it error, and if Yes where and what's the error?

Comment: Hi Tim, no error pops up after removing that line. The code run but simply not working. I figured the reason is because when a user enter a font name (say Calibri), so searchFont =  Calibri, but usually .Name needs to be = to something within " ", like .Name = "Calibri". So my question is how can I make the input variable entered from Calibri to "Calibri"

Comment: @Gerald, it is not required to enclose your variable within `" "`. When you do, it becomes a string and no more a variable. Also, your code works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks Arul. So I guess the only way to do this is to ask the user to key in the " " when they input eg. "Arial" so that the variable stored is in line with the vba syntax.

Comment: No, that is not required. Your code works as it is.

Comment: How exactly is you code failing? There are a couple of things I can see that might not fly:  If the text is in e.g. Calibri and the user types calibri, it won't work. I've edited your code to UCase the font names; that'll solve that problem. Also, if there are different fonts in one textrange, your code will fail. It's better to look at each of the .TextRange.Runs(x).Font.Name  collection members. Your code won't see text in shapes that are part of groups, text in tables, text in SmartArt, etc.